# Restrict the AWS ElasticSearch access to an auto scaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, amazon-policy

I have an AutoScaling group who must have the access to the AWS ElasticSearch Service,
But as you know, using IP address as access policies will not work in this case (The ip change every time).
I wonder if there is a way to use IAM Roles or Security groups to limit the access to the auto scaling group.
If there is can you give me an example?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You specify which IAM users or roles should have access to your
>   domain. All requests to the domain must be signed with AWS Signature
>   Version 4 signing. When a request reaches the domain, it is forwarded
>   to IAM for signature verification and access control.

A policy Like:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/susan"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-west-2:123456789012:domain/mydomain/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Replace the user ARN and domain ARN in red with those from the generated policy.

Refer [AWS Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/set-access-control-for-amazon-elasticsearch-service/)